# I'm looking for a comic where Huey, Dewey or Louie has a girlfriend

Tags: identification-request, comics

It's a series of still images (comic). I believe it's quite old, probably from between 1960-1980. It's about Huey, Dewey and Louie. Two of them are being sort of rowdy, fighting, doing mischief, etc. and messing up their clothes. Then someone says (roughly) that one of the brothers has a girlfriend and that it's easy to see who it is. Then in the last panel we see that one of the brothers is sitting with very neat clothes and acting very innocently. Then they say that he is the one with the girlfriend. I've been trying to find this cartoon, but without luck. Can anyone help point me to it?

Comment: Not sure that it's relevant, but at some point Daisy Duck gained her own set of triplet nieces: April, May and June. Not sure if there was ever a hint of dating amongst the six, but it's not impossible.

Comment: https://mickey-and-friends.fandom.com/wiki/April,_May_and_June notes that there is dating involved, although it's generally not clear who dates who (and they also note that in some incarnations, they'd be first-cousins at the least).